# Print dynamic list in pop up

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a list of dynamic length from columns A to F. (starts at row 1) I need to make a code to have this list printed on a pop up. I don not want it printed on another sheet, the sheet this list is on is very hidden. I need to minimize copying these numbers thus why i don't want it on another sheet.

The proble is as i said this list is of dynamis length. So I'd have something like:

```
msgbox(upf.cells(1,1) & " " & upf.cells(1,2) & " " & upf.cells(1,3) & " " & upf.cells(1,4) _
       upf.cells(2,1) & " " & upf.cells(2,2) & " " & upf.cells(2,3) & " " & upf.cells(2,4) _
       ... up to row lr)
```

How can I write this in some sort of a for i= 1 to lr loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a basic example...

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim upf As Range
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim sMsg As String

    Set upf = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))

    For rIndex = 1 To upf.Rows.Count
        For cIndex = 1 To upf.Columns.Count
            sMsg = sMsg & " " & upf.Cells(rIndex, cIndex)
        Next cIndex
    Next rIndex

    MsgBox Mid(sMsg, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: this works but creates another problem: the string gets overloaded and some items are missing at the end of the string. Is there a way of loading the string so it does not fill or matbe make it in 2 strings?

Comment: actualy i realized its not the string that is too small; it's the messagebox. It doesn't strech enough to englobe all the text. Any other solution?

Comment: The code is meant to be a starting point.  You could output the string to a text file, or to separate cells in the worksheet, or however you want.